# find RPM from Pulse of motor

Tags: arduino, pid-controller

I have an electronic gearbox motor with the following details:

25GA-370-12V -330RPM

I want to find a PID control  for this motor in Matlab. I take data from this motor by Arduino Due driver and an Arduino program.

The duration of printing of test is 0.003 sec (per 0.003 sec how many pulse show) and any 800=(2*400) pulse is one round in motor.

So I have some data about time and how many pulses at that time.  The motor has both CW and CCW rotation.  My problem is how can I find the RPM from the pulse?

I don't know how to change pulse with witch formula.

For example: at the  time of 1347544 after start I have 122 pulses but I can't find the way to change it to RPM at this period
i can put my Arduino code for you to know what i say

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. If you have a friend or contact who speaks good English I suggest you ask them to help you with the wording. This question will probably be closed because people do not understand it **BUT** if you can explain better the question will be reopened.

Comment: What I've managed to glean from your question (to which I've posted an answer) is that you have a motor which outputs 800 pulses per revolution and, that during a 3 millisecond  period, you managed to count 122 pulses. Is that what you're saying and, if it is, may I edit your question to reflect that before it gets sequestered by the thug squad?

Comment: LoL, I'm an Iranian but I cannot understand what you are saying! yep, this question is going to be locked because we cannot understand what you are saying!

Comment: @ PeterJ, Leon Heller, Olin Lathrop, tcrosley, pjc50: The question asked was: "find RPM from Pulse of motor" and the data given were: 1. the number of tach pulses in a single revolution of the motor shaft and 2. the number of tach pulses acquired during a 3 millisecond window. So what's unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what that "1347544" is about, if the motor shaft rotates 360 degrees per 800 pulses and you've accumulated 122 pulses during the 3 millisecond sampling interval, then the shaft will have rotated 54.9 degrees during that 3 milliseconds, which is 18,300 degrees (50.83 revolutions) per second. Then, since there are 60 seconds in 1 minute, the shaft will have been rotating at 3050 RPM during the 3 millisecond pulse acquisition window.